# Numpy.where raise KeyError with pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm working with incomplete data that split around files with different data structure. So I wrote a script with np.where to check if keys in column names and if it is write em in df.
I'm using pandas with np.where and it raise KeyError. Example:

```
df['col_result'] = np.where('col1' in df.columns, df['col1'], 'None')

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2894             try:
-> 2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'col1'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: If 'col1' is not in df.columns, np.where will *still* evaluate df['col1'] anyway, and consequently raise a KeyError. (Or more likely, np.where evaluates df['col1'], and then moves on to process its first argument.)

Comment: Any clarification on my answer required ?   Let me know whether it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

As you are testing whether `col1` is in the columns of `df`, it seems it is possible `col1` is not available in the columns.  For such condition, it will raise `KeyError` for `col1` when you code `df['col1']` in the code.

As you want to assign a whole column to a new column, you don't get much benefit from using `np.where()` (which mostly is used when reach row can meet or not meet a condition).  Thus, you can consider changing the codes to simple if-else statement, as follows:

```
if 'col1' in df.columns:
    df['col_result'] = df['col1']
else:
    df['col_result'] = 'None'
```